# 3-D Data Structure Display Design:

Tags: data-structures, language-agnostic, 3d

I am without a solution for a 3-D Data Structure Display and would like some advice.

Each of `n` nodes has `k` children. The `k` children are distributed across the bounding sphere of the node by a sphere electron-charge algorithm. While not technically accurate, it is easiest to say that the children are "equally distributed" across the bounding sphere of the node.

Currently, I am representing nodes by spheres. However for large `n`, this becomes computationally inefficient to display dynamically, due to the complexity of drawing a sphere.

It is necessary for the solution to have understandable and visually regular representations for all choices of `n` and `k_i`, visually regular meaning that if one line is perpendicular to two faces of two nodes, then all lines are perpendicular to some choice of two faces of some choice of two nodes, et cetera.

I have a few options here:

1. Use a sphere-drawing algorithm which uses fewer faces to represent a sphere.

   - This will look ugly, the lines extending from the "sphere" will not exit the figure flushly (a line from "sphere" A to "sphere" B will not be guaranteed to be perpendicular to the entrance face of A or B, much less both.)
2. Use Convex Regular Polyhedra instead of spheres, such that the number of faces of the polyhedron is equal to the number of children. This would allow lines to be draw perpendicular to both Polyhedron A and Polyhedron B.

   - This is Mathematically impossible, as there are only 5 such figures with non-variably many faces, but this structure requires that there be enough faces to map `k` points. The argument holds similarly if we try to map to vertices.
3. Use ???? Polyhedra, but draw lines from vertices to vertices.

   - I believe that this would always work, because, as far as I can tell, the lines I am drawing outline these polyhedra anyway. But, I do not know an efficient algorithm to draw these polyhedra and I do not know the name of them to look this up myself.
4. Any suggestions the community may have for me.

I have attached an image to illustrate the structure of my display. This is a structure with a root node, with 30 children. The root node's children have no children.

[image: Structure]

I have attached a second picture, with no nodes drawn, to show an example of the polyhedra described in 3, if what I meant was not already apparent.

[image: Polyhedron]

Comment: What's your lighting model? If you only have light sources at infinity, no shadows, no reflections, then all spheres look the same (except for the size). You may render a sphere once and then just scale the image down as needed. For a  more complicated model, there's not enough data to answer the question...

Comment: If I understand what you are saying, then you are discussing if I am generating a static image -- rendering, the model. I would like instead for this to be dynamically displayed with rotations, insertions, removals, et cetera, within a UI. If I have misunderstood you, then I shall still answer your question: I have no shadows or reflections, lights only at the infinities.

Comment: The view of the sphere only changes when the observer changes the direction of his view. Then you will need to render the sphere again. While the observer is stationary, you may use the same image for all spheres. I also forgot that if you want to simulate a wide-angle camera, you will need to take perspective into account (spheres located off the frame center look more like ellipses, so you need to stretch the image, not only scale, but this should still be easier than full render).

Comment: Ah. Sorry. It should have made sense the first time you said that. I'm a bit tired. The only problem with this is deciding in which order to draw the lines and the spheres, as a sphere behind a line should not hide that line from the observer, though if I just "copy and paste" a sphere after drawing all of the lines, that's what will happen.

Comment: How do you solve this problem when using the inefficient rendering algorithm? If by using Z-buffer, then you can still use Z-buffer, by scaling and shifting the "reference sphere" Z-space "image" (the height map).  But I think it should be easier to draw things in the reverse-depth order, and shorten the lines so that they only reach the spheres' surfaces, not centers. If sphere A is farther than B, you draw A first, then any line between A and B, then B.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the spheres with squares and give them the aspect of a sphere using ad hoc shaders.
To display lines as if they are popping from the surface of the sphere just make it this way: set the starting and ending point to the surface of the spheres (calculating the coordinates is simple math).